# How to convert a String data type to XML format in Java?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

I am working on this web application and the values that I capture from the form is passed to a stored procedure. Now, one of the parameters of the stored procedure accepts a XML String. The parameter is called "DetailOld" and I have no clue how to convert the string values from the form into an XML string.
Can anyone please help me out?

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
       // processRequest(request, response);
        PrintWriter out1 = response.getWriter();
         out1.println("Hey");
        try {
            // processRequest(request, response);
            out1.println("Servlet ");
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Connectioncheck.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Connection conn = null;
                PreparedStatement myStmt = null;
                int num = -1;

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://MPESA\\SQL2012;user=realm;password=friend;database=ElmaTest");
            if(conn!=null)
            {
                out1.print("Connection succesful");

              try{  


                myStmt = conn
                    .prepareStatement("exec p_AddEditAccountCustomer ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?");

                if(myStmt!=null)
                {
               String mnumber = request.getParameter("mobilenumber");
                String mtitle = request.getParameter("Title");
                 String fname= request.getParameter("firstname");
                String mName = request.getParameter("MiddleName");
                String lname = request.getParameter("LastName");
                 String maddress = request.getParameter("address");
                 String melmaid = request.getParameter("elmaid");
                 String mcity = request.getParameter("City");
                 String mId = request.getParameter("Idtype");
                 String midno = request.getParameter("idno");
                 String operatorid = "1";
                 String BankId = "99";
                 String Country = "Kenya";
                 String customercountry = "1";
                 String maccntid = request.getParameter("accountid");
                 String accounttype="1";
                 String cardnumber ="1";
                 String mcurrency = request.getParameter("currency");
                String branchid = "1";
                String AliasName="1";

                String createdBy="1";
                String createdOn ="2016-11-02";
                String DetailOld = "1";`//this is what the procedure //expects as an XML string. I have used the default value 1 for testing //purpose.`
                String DetailNew = "1";
                String ModuleId="2001";
                String eventId="1";
                myStmt.setString(1, mnumber);
                myStmt.setString(2, mtitle);
                myStmt.setString(3, fname);
                myStmt.setString(4, mName);
                myStmt.setString(5, lname);
                myStmt.setString(6, maddress );
                myStmt.setString(7, melmaid);
                myStmt.setString(8,mcity);
                myStmt.setString(9, mId );
                myStmt.setString(10, midno);
                myStmt.setString(11,operatorid );
                myStmt.setString(12, BankId );
                myStmt.setString(13, Country);
                myStmt.setString(14, customercountry );
                myStmt.setString(15, maccntid);
                myStmt.setString(16, accounttype);
                myStmt.setString(17, cardnumber);
                myStmt.setString(18, mcurrency);
                myStmt.setString(19, branchid);
                myStmt.setString(20,AliasName );
                myStmt.setString(21, createdBy);
                myStmt.setString(22,createdOn);
                myStmt.setString(23, DetailOld);
                myStmt.setString(24, DetailNew );
                myStmt.setString(25, ModuleId);
                myStmt.setString(26,eventId);
                myStmt.executeQuery();

                }

              }catch (SQLException exc) {
                  exc.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

                   //out1.println("Done properly");
                   response.sendRedirect("CustomerDetails.jsp");



                  myStmt.close();
                  conn.close();
        }



















            }

        }  catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Connectioncheck.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }
```

XML format- 
String detailold-

```
<Table1>
  <CustomerID>1916507095</CustomerID>
  <AccountType>BANK</AccountType>
  <Country>kenya</Country>
  <BankID>99</BankID>
  <BankAccountID>001001000095</BankAccountID>
  <TitleOfAccount>Mr</TitleOfAccount>
  <FirstName>Pramod1</FirstName>
  <MiddleName>Kb1</MiddleName>
  <LastName>Sahoo</LastName>
  <BranchID>000</BranchID>
  <TypeOfID>Driving License</TypeOfID>
  <IDNumber>276999</IDNumber>
  <EmailID>Pramodk@CS.com</EmailID>
  <Address>Nairobi</Address>
  <City>AWENDO</City>
  <CardNumber>kenya</CardNumber>
  <CurrencyID>KES</CurrencyID>
  <AliasName>pramod</AliasName>
</Table1>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create java class with getter setter (POJO) - say Detailold.java
2. Populate that POJO object with data that you are getting from database in loop.
3. Convert that object to XML using JAXB

Here is one example how to convert data into XML using JAXB - https://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/